# Uniqueness of a 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a second order differential equation of the form

$y''(x)+f(x)y'(x)+j(x)y(x)=g(x)$

on the interval $[0,\infty)$, where $f,j$ and $g$ are continuous functions. Are the conditions $y(0)=y_0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} y'(x)=c$ with $c$ being some constant enough to ensure the existence of a unique solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for example, the functions on the form
$$
y(x)=C_1\exp(-x)+C_2\exp(-2x)+1
$$
all satisfy
$$
y''(x)+3y'(x)+2y(x)=2
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}y'(x)=0.
$$
However,
$$
y_0=y(0)=C_1+C_2+1,
$$
So any values of $C_1$ and $C_2$ satisfying $C_1+C_2=y_0-1$ will give you a solution.

Comment: Indeed, many thanks!